# How can I find the "mini collectibles" in tomb raider?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In every area, there are things to collect. Most of their locations you can get from treasure maps, skills that reveal them, or being close enough when using survival instincts.

However, there is one type that does not appear like that. In the very first area you have to destroy wooden totems that hang from trees, in the second one you have to destroy lanterns, etc

Is there a way to easily find them, or is the only way to just look everywhere closely? I am missing 1 in the first two areas and it's preventing me from reaching 100%

Comment: Are you willing to [follow a guide](http://www.gamechup.com/tomb-raider-all-totem-and-lantern-locations-video-guide/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find them the hard way. They're meant to be optional side challenges, so no help is given to you while looking for them.